# Unknown syntax with multiplication?

Tags: notation, products

So I have an assignment and this formula showed up:

$$\prod_{i<j} \;[\,p(j) - p(i)\,]$$

I have seen the multiplication sign before, I know what it is, but I don't know what '$i<j$' means in this context.

EDIT: I've looked all around the web for it, and I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means "the product over all pairs $i, j$ where $i < j$."  For example, if $p(i)$ is defined for $i = 1, 2, 3$, then
$$
\prod_{i<j} \;[\,p(j) - p(i)\;] = [ p(2) - p(1) ] [p(3) - p(1)] [p(3) - p(2)].
$$

Comment: Ha, logical indexing!

Answer (score 8):

It means the product of every version of the expression in which $i <j $ and $i $ and $j $ are in some set implied from context.

Comment: They are in the set {1,2,...,8}

Comment: Then you can also think of it as 
$$\prod_{j=1}^8 \prod_{i=1}^{j-1} (p(j)-p(1))$$

Comment: @kccu, $p(1)$ should be $p(i)$ in your expression. And it might be more intuitive to have $j$ start at $2$.

Comment: @MarkS. Right, that's a typo. Unfortunately it's too late to edit. Thanks.

Comment: @kccu Moderators can edit any comments any time. If you feel it's too embarrassing or misleading, you can ask them in chat or raise a flag to ask for correction. (I'm not sure how mods on this site take such flags, though.) And of course there is the option of deleting and recommenting.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for the tip. Hopefully anyone who reads the comment will see the one below it correcting my typo.

Answer (score 1):

The notation indicates that you just should take the product for indices $i$ strictly less than some other index $j$. Surrounding context should indicate what $j$ is.

For example:

$j=4$

$$\prod_{i<j} p(i) = p(1) \times p(2) \times p(3)$$

Assuming your indexing starts from $i=1$.
Hard to say more without context where the formula appears.

Comment: This is possible, but in my experience it is more common that such a product is actually over both indices *i* and *j*. As is often the case, context determines what notation means.